# libfaketime and Mac OS, LD_PRELOAD

Tags: osx, c

Running Mac OS 10.7.2 and trying to run [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) and nothing happen.  I installed and ran exactly as directed only the time and date stay exactly as are set in the system?  Is anyone else able to successfully run this on OSX?

```
$ date
Mon Jan 30 21:05:09 CST 2012
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" date
Mon Jan 30 21:05:32 CST 2012
```

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/blob/master/README.OSX ? (That's directly linked from libfaketime's front page.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES instead of LD_PRELOAD on Mac OS.  You may need to set DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE as well.  E.g.

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libfaketime.so.1 DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=y FAKETIME="-15d" date
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compile the library like this:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC mylib.c -o mylib.so
```

You may create environment variables:

```
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./mylib.so
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=y
```

Then execute with the new loaded library:

```
./program
```

Obs:

> Working on macOS High Sierra (v 10.13.1)